# Add last digit or letter to a checkbox checkbox + "1".checked = true

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I´d like to be able to acces a `Checkbox` (or `Textbox` or similar) by just adding the last digit or letter like this:

```
int number = 1;
CheckBox tempCheckbox = "myform.checkBoxTool" + number;
tempCheckbox.Checked = true;
```

I guess this is already covered but I cant seem to find the right search words.

Comment: How about putting them in a List (or Array) and accesing it by index ( = your "number") ?

Comment: Instead of having `checkBox1`, `checkBox2` and so on you should consider to create a **list of checkboxes**, which you can then access by their index: e.g. `theCheckBoxes[0]`.

Comment: You may also consider using property binding. In WPF, this is easily done using MVVM but also in WinForms it is absolutely no rocket science. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: I know about the list/array option thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several opportunities. The most obvious is to use the `ControlsCollection` of your `Form`:

```
var checkBox = myForm.Controls["myform.checkBoxTool" + number];
```

Alternativly go with [`ControlCollection.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_):

```
var checkBox = myForm.Controls.Find("myform.checkBoxTool" + number, true).FirstOrDefault();
```

However if you have multiple checkboxes that all differ only by a single index, it´s a better idea to store them as a list or array of `CheckBox` in the first place:

```
List<CheckBox> myCheckBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
```

Now you can easily access them by index:

```
var checkBox = myChekBoxes[number];
```

Be aware that indices - as any number in .NET - are zero-based. So the very first element in the list has index zero.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the list/array option but its not what I´m looking for here.
If I use your first option, how do I check/uncheck it?

Comment: @JeeyBee cast to `CheckBox` and set the property? `var checkBox = ((CheckBox) myForm.Controls["myform.checkBoxTool" + number]); checkBox.Checked = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if `tempCheckbox` is on the *same form* where the *querying code* is, you can try *Linq*;

```
using System.Linq;

...

public partial class MyForm : Form {
  ...

  int number = 1;

  CheckBox tempCheckbox = this
    .Controls
    .Find($"checkBoxTool{number}", true) // we don't want "myform." here
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .FirstOrDefault();

  // If check box found, check it
  if (tempCheckbox != null)
    tempCheckbox.Checked = true;
```

A better approach is to organize these controls into a collection, e.g. `Dictionary`:

```
  public partial class MyForm : Form {
    private Dictionary<int, CheckBox> m_CheckBoxTools = new Dictionary<int, CheckBox>();

    public MyForm() {
      InitializeComponent();

      m_CheckBoxTools.Add(1, checkBoxTool1);
      m_CheckBoxTools.Add(3, checkBoxTool3); 
      m_CheckBoxTools.Add(25, checkBoxTool25);
    }
```

Then you can query the dictionary

```
    if (m_CheckBoxTools.TryGetValue(number, out CheckBox tempCheckbox)) {
      tempCheckbox.Checked = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use something like below

```
CheckBox chkList1 =new CheckBox();

chkList1.Text = strCheckboxText;

chkList1.ID="Chk"+intControlIndex;

chkList1.Font.Name = "Verdana";

chkList1.Font.Size = 9;

chkList1.Checked = true;

this.Form.Controls.Add(chkList1);
```

then you can check existing check box and find your ID. Assuming checkbox is in Panel control.

```
   string str1="";
   foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) c).Checked)                      
        str1 += c.ID+ ", "; 
    }

    str1=str1.Trim();
```

Comment: OP wants to access an existing checkbox, not to create a new one